# angularjs accordion by default needs to open

Tags: angularjs

on click on "toggle" i want to toggle the div
a) how to keep the div content by default open / show?
b) onclick how to toggle the class to achieve icon change from down to up?

Please refer the below fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/EhTZW/572/

HTML:

```
<h3>Toggle  with AngularJS</h3>

<div ng-app id="ng-app">
    <hr />
    <a href="#" ng-model="collapsed" ng-click="collapsed=!collapsed" class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down">Toggle</a>

    <div ng-show="collapsed">I am description for the above title, which was collapsed by default</div>
    <hr />

</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<h3>Toggle  with AngularJS</h3>

<div ng-app id="ng-app">
<hr />
<!--use ng-class for conditions-->
<a href="#" ng-model="collapsed" ng-click="collapsed=!collapsed" class="glyphicon" ng-class="{'glyphicon-chevron-down':collapsed, 'otherIcon': !collapsed}">Toggle</a>
<!--ng-show to !collapsed for default open-->
<div ng-show="!collapsed">I am description for the above title, which was collapsed by default</div>
<hr />

</div>
```

Comment: Zarmarrowski: thanks, but the icon change is not happening!!

Comment: @Krish sorry, put single quotes in classes: ng-class="{'glyphicon-chevron-down':collapsed, 'otherIcon': !collapsed}"

Answer (score 1):

To change icon you can use **[`ngClass`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass)**

To make content visible by default , convert you `ng-show` to `ng-hide`

Try like this

```
<a href="#" ng-model="collapsed" ng-click="collapsed=!collapsed" class="glyphicon" ng-class="{'glyphicon-chevron-down' : !collapsed , 'glyphicon-chevron-up' : collapsed }">Toggle</a>
<div ng-hide="collapsed">I am description for the above title, which was collapsed by default</div>
```

<kbd>**[`DEMO`](http://jsfiddle.net/aiubian/EhTZW/573/)**</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

You just need to `set` the value of `collapsed=true` at the beginning

Comment: Would you mind clicking the "edit" link below your Answer and adding a code example to demonstrate what you mean? That would increase the quality of your contribution to fit the StackOverflow site guidelines...

Answer (score 0):

you can use something like this

I am description for the above title, which was collapsed by default